# Use "javascript:" in href attribute to change value of button

Tags: javascript, html

Why doesn't this work in a browser?

```
<input type="button" id="x">
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('x').value='something';">Click</a>
```

Yes, I know that I can use onClick to call a function and put my code there, but is there a way to use 'javascript:' with the href attribute to do simple javascript functions like changing a value?

Comment: This seems to work fine when tested (Chrome 28): http://jsfiddle.net/ez447/. Any more details you can offer with regards to how you're using this? (Browser version, other code, etc.)

Comment: @Serlite: In Chrome 36 it replaces the document with the string sequence "something".

Comment: @FelixKling Looks like (my old versions of) Firefox and IE do the same thing too. I guess Chrome 28 is just special...

Comment: @Serlite: I don't think it's working for you even. As I check the link you provided (jsfiddle), it replaces the whole frame with that text 'something', whereas it is supposed to change the text of the button only.

Comment: @singh No, in Chrome 28 it does what the OP expects it to do: change the value of the `<input>` to "something". This appears to be inconsistent with what the majority of others are experiencing, though.

Comment: @Serlite: really? hmm.. that's strange. thanks for sharing btw.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment "returns" the value assigned. Returning any kind of value from a `javascript:` link indicates to the browser that it should replace the document with that value.

Usually you might see `javascript:void(stuff goes here)` to suppress the return value.

You already seem to be aware of why you shouldn't do this, though. `onClick` event handler is a step in the right direction, but really it should be attached externally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should work and as you know onclick is another easy approach to do it;

However if you still want to it with href you may try this - 
(this might look unwillingly big :)

```
<input type="button" id="x">
<a href="javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('x').value='something';})();">Click</a>
```